# Access JS promise .then() inside promise executor

Tags: javascript, promise

Is it possible to add code that'll be executed after some promise is resolved inside this promise executor?

It would look something like this:

```
var loading = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    app.initialize();
    loading.then(/* some extra code */); //loading is undefined
    resolve(app);
});
```

But doing it this way, `loading` seems to be undefined yet.

Comment: No, because the executor is immediately executed by the `Promise` constructor, even before the promise object is returned

Comment: `app.initialize()` should probably return a promise? I feel like some context is missing...

Answer (score 4):

short answer is no. what is the problem with this:

```
const loading = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    app.initialize();
    resolve(app);
}).then(app => {
    // something else.
})
```